# after deploying in heroku an error was popped up

Tags: node.js, heroku

"Heroku app successfully deploying, but receiving application error when loading site."

I have all the necessary file in server but it's still shows this error after successfully deployed.

heroku logs --tail is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v66G.png)as on given image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It says, "Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch". Have you searched for that error message?

Comment: You haven't provided much information, but I suspect at least one of the 36 answers on the marked duplicate will help you. If you are running an HTTP server, bind to the port given by `process.env.PORT`. If you aren't running an HTTP server you probably want to run a `worker` process instead of a `web` process.